# Is it possible to reduce the number of variables in bin packing?

Tags: np-complete, integer-programming

The bin packing problem can be formulated as:
\begin{align}
 & \underset{x,y}{\min}
 & & B = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\\
 & \text{subject to} 
 & & B \geq 1,\\
 & & & \sum_{j=1}^n a_j x_{ij} \leq V y_i,\forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\\
    & & & \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 1,\forall j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}\\
    & & & y_i \in \{0,1\},\forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\},\\
    & & & x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}, \forall i \in \{1,\ldots,n\}, \, \forall j \in \{1,\ldots,n\},\\
\end{align}

where $y_i = 1$ if bin $i$ is used and $x_{ij} = 1$ if item $j$ is put into bin $i$.

Why do we use $x_{ij}$ and $y_{i}$? We can just use $x_{ij}$.

- if $x_{ij}=1$ than bin $i$ is used and item $j$ is put into bin $i$; and
- if $x_{ij}=0$ than bin $i$ is not used.

Is that correct? If so, why can't I find any formulation with only $x_{ij}$?

Comment: They look equivalent. Definitely $y_i$s look redundant. But the objective (sum of $y_i$s) will be harder to express.

Comment: Try to write an equivalent formulation with $x_{ij}$ and see if it works. You don't need us for that.

Comment: I think that if I remove $y_i$ from all the constraints in the optimization problem and replace the objective function by $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\max\limits_{j}x_{ij}$. That will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integer program, or more properly an integer *linear* program, consists of a linear program together with integrality constraints stating that some of the variables are integers. As such, its objective function is always a linear combination of variables.

When the objective is minimization, it is *admissible* to have $\max$ operators (appearing positively) in the objective function. This means that there is an equivalent proper integer program. This program is obtained by introducing auxiliary variables, just as the variables $y_i$ are introduced in your example to implement $\max_j x_{ij}$.

To answer your question, it all depends on what you consider as an integer program. The standard definition only allows linear objective functions, and in this case the $y_i$ are necessary. If you also allow $\max$ operators in the objective function, then the $y_i$ are not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Decided to post an answer here:

You can get by with only $x_{ij}$s in this case. However, the objective function now becomes harder to define.

A cleaner way to work with bin packing is to turn it into a decision problem (you can convert it back to optimisation problem by doing a binary search, hence it doesn't add an exponential factor).

Comment: I think the objective function $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\max\limits_{j}x_{ij}$ will work, right?

Comment: Oh, Yuval answered that question. You can't use max in classical integer programming.